# Google Chrome on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, x11, chrome, google

I have configured an `Ubuntu` server (16.04.1), with minimum dependencies, to be able to run `Google Chrome` on that server via the command line.

I installed: `X11`, `Xvfb`, `xorg`, and `Google Chrome`, but when I try to start Chrome, I receive the error message:

> [ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(265)] Gtk: cannot open display.

I could use any hint about what's wrong or steps that I can follow to start Chrome on a server.

Comment: Don't forget the 'Gtk libraries...

Comment: This [Q/A](http://superuser.com/questions/407043/is-it-possible-to-run-graphical-applications-such-as-firefox-without-installing) may help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install and start a desktop environment then run Google Chrome within it. You can choose from any one really but if you want something lightweight like `lxde`.

`sudo apt-get install lxde`

Install that and then add `exec startlxde`, on its own line, to the end of the `~/.xsession` file.

Finally run `startx` and then from within `lxde` run Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You must of course start a graphical session before starting Google Chrome; for example, `startx`. Then launch the browser from withing the graphical session.